# Phonegap WindowsPhone app only shows PhoneGap icon

Tags: android, ios, node.js, windows-phone, phonegap-build

This is really weird and I have no clue how to start fixing the problem.

Recently I developed an application using Nodejs, React and Redux.

Once finished I created *.xap*, *.ipa* and *.apk* files using PhoneGap building online service.

After published to every store (iOS, Google Play, Windows Market), everything worked just fine for Android and Apple versions of the app (.ipa and .apk).

But WindowsPhone app **only shows a blank screen and then the PhoneGap logo** (a cube with eyes).

[image: This is an actual device]

Android and Apple versions work fine. But in the WindowsPhone version I don't even get to the main screen.

Any idea about how to start tackling this problem?

Have anyone experienced something similar?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

UPDATE:

It seems to be a known issue without solution from PhoneGap.

https://c.getsatisfaction.com/nitobi/topics/windows_8_mobile_blank_screen_on_load?topic-reply-list[settings][page]=1#topic-reply-list

Comment: Your description is poor I have no idea what you are saying. The icon you are seeing is the default icon that is loaded when you do not define an icon for the app.

Comment: How to clarify this... The same hybrid app was published for Android, iOS and WindowsPhone. Android and iOS are working just fine.

For WindowsPhone, all I get is the image above, nothing else, no login screen, no landing screen, no nothing.

It's the same source code which is working in Android and iOS but not in WindowsPhone.

Comment: I go that, but I have not idea what the "app does. Nor can I see your source code or `config.xml`, so I cannot help you. Frankly, I'm baffled as to how you could "publish" on the "App" stores without first testing.

Comment: Your try to help is appreciated. Of course all was tested in emulators. Your personal appreciations or your "baffled" feeling don't help. Thanks again.

Comment: For any other viewer: All I need is to know if this has happened to anyone. If so, then that's the right person to provide a solution, clue or feedback.

Comment: Your English is not good. I guess I must be direct. What do you mean by "publish"? Do you mean the app is in the App store? if so, please provide a link so I have an idea about what we are talking about.

Comment: I'm sorry. English is not my native language. When I say "published" I mean the app is in the App store. Which word would be the correct one? Anyways, here is a link to the app with the problem: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/ets-mobile/9nblggh5f15n Thanks again.

Comment: I don't want to see the broken app. The working app please.